# Is it possible to search for words by definition on Wiktionary?

Tags: vocabulary

... Or are there better alternative to Wiktionary for looking up words by definition online.

Comment: What do you mean by looking up words by definition? An English-to-Latin dictionary? Perhaps an example would illuminate the concept if it's hard to describe.

Comment: If you are specifically looking for an online dictionary of Latin, you might want the Latin Wiktionary, e.g. https://la.wiktionary.org/wiki/bird_(en) gives a Latin definition for the English word 'bird'. Not sure how complete or user-friendly it is.

Answer (score 2):

Wiktionary links words together by meaning in the “Translations” section that you will find in many entries. So suppose you want to know the Latin word (or words) for “barrel,” you look up [barrel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barrel) on Wiktionary, scroll to the English noun, look for the [Translations section](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/barrel#Translations), expand (say) the entry for “round vessel made from staves bound with a hoop” and will find the Latin entries *cupa* and *dolium*, also linked.

If you want an English-to-Latin dictionary, this is more or less the least convenient thing you could do. There are good English-to-Latin dictionaries, some of them even online. One of the best is Smith & Hall's, which you will [find at Latinitium](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/) (entry for barrel [here](https://latinitium.com/latin-dictionaries/?t=sh2064) – incredibly I chose, by pure accident, a rare case where the Wiktionary method will arguably be more helpful, because Smith & Hall for whatever pedantic reason suggest neither *cupa* nor *dolium*, but the atrocious *ligneum vas circulis cinctum*).

Answer (score 1):

It's crude, but Perseus allows you to look up words based on what English words occur in Lewis & Short or Elementary Lewis definitions. Use the option "English-to-[Language] lookup" on this page: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/search

For example, looking up "bird" this way gives an assortment of results that include *avis, accipiter, aliger* and various names of specific birds.